# About File file = new File(path)

Tags: java, java-io

The [Java.iO.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) document says the following words about its constructor which takes the `pathname`:

> `public File(String pathname)`
>
> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string 
>       into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string, 
>       then the result is the empty abstract pathname.

But what if the `pathname` points to a file which is **already existing**?

```
File file = new File(PATH_TO_AN_EXISTING_FILE);
```

Does the above `file` instance represent a fresh new file (with the existing one be deleted?) **Or** does it represent the existing file ?

Comment: I don't see a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the documentation says is that it will create a new `File` *instance*.  This mean it will create a new instance in memory of the `File` class.

This object will point to a file on you file system.  However, if the file exists, it will not create a new file.

Answer (score 4):

I think the documentation is a little confusing: creating a new `File` object in Java does not mean creation of a new file in your file system. The `File` object is merely an abstract representation of file and directory pathname, it may or may not represent a real file on disk or on a network storage.

It is more or less equivalent to a `String` representing an address of something: when you write

```
String str = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500";
```

you create a string with an address of an existing building. There is no other connection between the string `str` that you created and The White House that happens to be located at that address.

The only difference between a `File` created with an existing path name and a file created with a non-existent path name is that the call of `exists()` on the former will return `true`, while the same call on the later would return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

A `File` is not directly linked to an actual file on the file system. If the file exists, it will point to that file. If the file doesn't exist, it will not create it. `exist()` will return false.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.io.File` class represents a path on some file system. It is not directly bound to a file. You are *not* opening a file when you create a `File` instance.

A `File` object is merely an object on the heap. Yes, it does have fields and methods that imply that this object represents a real file (or a directory: see the ambiguity?).
You can create `File` objects for files/directories that do not exist: nothing will happen to the file system; the `File` instances will be created. After all, a `File` is just a descriptor.

Furthermore, you can create several `File` objects with different paths (esp. when one is absolute and others are relative from different parent paths), but they will all point to the same file/directory when they are actually evaluated (by opening a file with `In/OutputStream`, `Reader/Writer`; when checking with `exists()` or creating: `createFile()`, `createDirectory()`.

Comment: But I will later update the content of the file, I am wondering is the existing file will be replaced by a fresh file or not

Comment: I guess these types of ambiguities is part of why Java 7 features the `Path` class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusingly named class.

A `File` object represents a **file path, not an actual file**. So when you create a `File` object you do not change anything on the filing system. Conceptually, it's no different to a `String`.

In java.nio, the class has been renamed to (the much more intuitive) `Path`.

Answer (score 0):

File f=new File("C://Existing_file")

above line indicates already existed file not the new one to be created file.
File class instance always refers to IO operations and also it always refers to already consisted file

Answer (score 0):

By creating new instance

```
File f= new File("ABC.txt");
```

This new object of file will point to a file named *ABC.txt* in your system, if present. If the *ABC.txt* file is not there, then the file object simply does not point to any file.

Answer (score 0):

When a file is stored in a computer. The information related to the file is also stored( you can check it in the properties by right clicking on file). These are those information that is about the file.

So the File class object does nothing except represents the information about the file.

The File class object only provides you with information about the file and the same is stated in its definition.